# Who is trying to login with my username?

Tags: login-errors

Since this morning there have been non-stop login attempts against a particular username -all of them failing. There are no active Apex Jobs or batches running and the debug logs are not producing any logs, so we are not sure who or what is responsible.

Login History (showing the last few attempts)

```
Login Time                  Source IP               Login Type      Status              Browser Platfor App Cli API Type        API Version Login URL   Community
12/1/2015 9:22:33 PM CST    Salesforce.com IP       Other Apex API  Login Rate Exceeded Unknown Unknown N/A N/A SOAP Partner    33.0         
12/1/2015 9:22:33 PM CST    Salesforce.com IP       Other Apex API  Login Rate Exceeded Unknown Unknown N/A N/A SOAP Partner    33.0         
12/1/2015 9:22:32 PM CST    Salesforce.com IP       Other Apex API  Login Rate Exceeded Unknown Unknown N/A N/A SOAP Partner    33.0         
12/1/2015 9:22:32 PM CST    Salesforce.com IP       Other Apex API  Login Rate Exceeded Unknown Unknown N/A N/A SOAP Partner    33.0         
12/1/2015 9:22:31 PM CST    Salesforce.com IP       Other Apex API  Login Rate Exceeded Unknown Unknown N/A N/A SOAP Partner    33.0         
12/1/2015 9:22:31 PM CST    Salesforce.com IP       Other Apex API  Login Rate Exceeded Unknown Unknown N/A N/A SOAP Partner    33.0         
12/1/2015 9:22:30 PM CST    Salesforce.com IP       Other Apex API  Login Rate Exceeded Unknown Unknown N/A N/A SOAP Partner    33.0         
12/1/2015 9:22:30 PM CST    Salesforce.com IP       Other Apex API  Login Rate Exceeded Unknown Unknown N/A N/A SOAP Partner    33.0         
12/1/2015 9:22:30 PM CST    Salesforce.com IP       Other Apex API  Login Rate Exceeded Unknown Unknown N/A N/A SOAP Partner    33.0
```

This is locking up the user due to maximum login attempts.

Comment: in the source IP you are getting Salesforce.com IP?

Comment: That's right. It's copy pasted from Login History.

Comment: then its look SF is running some maintenance and they are trying to enter in your org. But i am not total sure here.

Comment: Seems kinda odd if it is salesforce that they are using and old API version (v33.0).

Comment: What other Apps you have installed?  This happened to my Org because I had Marketo API connecting all the time after changing the password in Salesforce.

Comment: similar to @NinjaKing -- my experience was with Zimbra Zimlets logging in regularly to sync mail objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out it was our Metadata API integration (called via a managed package).

Comment: Glad you found it - a good reminder that to the extent possible, API integrations should get dedicated users for traceability purposes.